# How replace to same class names with foreach/each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to convert plain text urls to `<a href=""></a>`. I've found a JS code that works. My problem is that my HTML structure needs that I modify the code, putting the current code inside a foreach.

My html:

```
<div class="content">Some text with links</div>
<div class="content">Some text with links</div>
<div class="content">Some text with links</div>
<div class="content">Some text with links</div>
<div class="content">Some text with links</div>
<div class="content">Some text with links</div>
```

The JS:

```
$(function()
{
    var re = /(https?:\/\/(([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?))/ig;    
    $('.content').html($('.content').html().replace(re, '<a href="$1" title="">$1</a>'));
});
```

The above JS works, but will populate all the div's with the same content. I've tried to put this code in a foreach but have failed. My poor JS knowledge makes me ask this on SO.

Can you give some clues on how to put this code in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions like `.html` allow a function to be passed. An `.each` loop is then done internally, and moreover you get the current value passed:

```
$('.content').html(function(i, current) {
  return current.replace(re, '<a href="$1" title="">$1</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`.html()` for retrieval only selects the *first* matched element.  You can do this pretty easily, though, because functions like `.html` can take a function argument for setting that iterates over each selected element individually.

```
$(".content").html(function (_, html) {
   return html.replace(re ...etc...);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to loop through each `.content` div, try this:

```
$('.content').each(function() {
    var $content = $(this);
    var re = /(https?:\/\/(([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?))/ig;    
    $content.html($content.html().replace(re, '<a href="$1" title="">$1</a>'));
});
```